# How do I pass value as session variable to parameter?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So far, we are able to pass form varialbe to our reports via reportviewer.

Below is our current code and works great.

Markup

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUser" Text="Enter UserName" />
            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td align="center">
                UserName:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" Width="75px" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGetUser" Text="Print" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Server code:

```
Sub Run_Report(ByVal sel As String)
    ReportViewer1.Reset()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Dim params_user(0) As ReportParameter


    Select Case which.Value

        Case "R"
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ObjectDataSource1.ID))
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "GetReceits.rdlc"
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
            params_user(0) = New ReportParameter("UserName", UserName.Text, False)
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params_user)

    End Select
End Sub
```

However, due to security reasons, we have been asked to pass session variables to report.

This way, users wouldn't have to enter their usernames in order to print the report.

I have tried changing this line:

```
    params_user(0) = New ReportParameter("UserName", UserName.Text, False)
```

to

```
params_user(0) = New ReportParameter("UserName", Session("UserName").ToString, False)
```

but when I attempted to run it, I get:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `Session("UserName")` is null surely

Answer (score 0):

If this works:

```
params_user(0) = New ReportParameter("UserName", UserName.Text, False)
```

And this throws a NullReferenceException:

```
params_user(0) = New ReportParameter("UserName", Session("UserName").ToString, False)
```

Then it seems like that `Session("UserName")` is null.

Two resolutions to that problem would be to either

1. populate `Session("UserName")` on page load (if it's empty), or
2. use `User.Identity.Name` in that call (if your users have already authenticated in some way).

**Option 1**
In your Page_Load code, you could do this:

```
If (Session("UserName") Is Nothing) Then
    Session("UserName") = "the user name"
End If
```

**Option 2**
If you are authenticating your users already, you should be able to pass in the [`Page.User.Identity.Name` value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
params_user(0) = New ReportParameter("UserName", User.Identity.Name, False)
```

Comment: @jadarney127, hi and thanks to all for the response.

User.Identity.Name assumes you are being authenticated via Active Directory, No?

We are not using Active Directory.

The Option 1 is a viable option but for some reason, I am still getting `object reference not set to instance of an object`

I have created a hiddenField markup and called it UserHide.

Then I am passing that Uhide as control ID to SelectParameters.

           ` <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UserHide" Name="UserName" PropertyName="Text" 
             Type="String" />`

How do I use it with yuor Option 1 solution?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh I think that User.Identity.Name gets populated even if you are using Forms Authentication (I've used it that way before).  I'll update my answer for Option 1 based on the additional information you gave just now.

Comment: By the way, @ChidiOkeh, you need to change your ControlParameter markup to be `PropertyName="Value"` (the asp:HiddenField uses the Value property to store information, not a Text property.  Does UserHide have the user's name in it when your page loads?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh I actually don't know what to update the answer with, because I don't know enough about UserHide.  Are you saying you want to use UserHide to populate the Session variable?  If you're using ControlParameters with a HiddenField, why do you need the Sesion variable?

Comment: my preferred approach would be to use session variable.

This way, as soon as user logs in, his/her id will be recognized and passed to the @UserName parameter of the report.

But I can't get that to work. As stated, when I do this:
`params_user(0) = New ReportParameter("UserName", Session("UserName").ToString, False)`, I expected the value of the session variable to be passed the param but I kept getting object reference error.

That's why I thought I could pass that to hidden field and then reference the hidden field. However...

Comment: I decided to use textbox control and keep the visibility hidden, pass the session variable to it and then pass it back to the control Id of UserName which I then referenced on the server code.

Seems to work but it is way too many wiggling.